# Web application + android app, how handle db connection on android

Tags: java, android, database, web-services, architecture

Recently I'm working on online application (Spring+Hibernate) and I also would like to have mobile app (android). Hibernate talks with DB in the web application, now, I have no idea how to communicate with DB from mobile, should I do it somehow through my web application, or do I have to create new one for that purpose, or maybe web services?

All feedback, comments and advices are highly appriciated!

Thans,

Comment: Do you want to access an external DB or internal DB from the phone? If  external - use a webservice json/xml.. If internal then you have to implement a service as well but internal Android service to talk to external webservice.

Comment: Let me put it this way, I'm not concerned about the architecture here - that we can change if necessary, I'm looking for most efficient solution, since webapp talks to db through hibernate, I thought we could exploit that somehow, is it possible at all? If not, what option would you choose in this scenario.

Comment: It is possible read my comment below. Hibernate is just your DAO framework. You will get your data via Hibernate and represent them in any possible way via any restful webservice (json/xml) or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write an API for your webapp.

Comment: How to actually do that, could you share some links, tutorials, any kind of relevant doc's?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html

Comment: REST WS?  Damn i acctualy thought 'bout that, but then I didn't know how to integrate that with what i've got so far. I'll have a look right away, but just to streight things up... i can use already developed Hibernate DB communication there?

Comment: Ofcourse you can. Hibernate is your DAO - you will write a class which will retrieve data using your Hibernate methods then represent them using Webservices and access via your android service app.

Answer (score -1):

Android provides a built in SQLite Database which can be accessed from code via [SQLiteDatabase Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) which is part of the android SDK. Just google the web for Tutorials, you will find plenty.

Ok, you want to communicate with the DB on the web server, sorry about that. Not sure how to do with Hibernate, but you can use JDBC to remotely connect to your database from the phone.
This works with normal Java code.

Comment: Dan, I'm not sure if connecting to DB straight from mobile is safe, I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: hmm I haven't considered that, but thinking of it it sounds reasonable.